# What's "logarifm" in Metapost and why I get the error "Undefined control sequence"?

Tags: metapost

I'm trying the following Metapost sample:

http://www.ursoswald.ch/metapost/tutorial/TeXLabels.html

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{input mpcolornames; beginfig(1);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
  input TeXLabels.mp
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

But I get the following error:

```
./main.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \setbox264\hbox{\cyr
                        logarifm i plowad\char126}
l.10 \end{mplibcode}
```

I've made some test and already know that the problem is in this line of `TeXLabel.mp`:

```
label.lft(btex 
          \cyr  logarifm i plowad\char126  
   etex scaled 1.1, (3.7, 2.4) transformed t);
```

I've already tried to replace "logarifm" with "logarithm" but it didn't work either.

Can you help me?

Comment: The error is in `\cyr` not being defined. The Russian word for “logarithm” is indeed “логарифм”. Just remove `\cyr` (and change the caption, I guess you don't use Russian).

Comment: OK. Cyrillic. Now it makes sense... Thank you!

Comment: By the way, the picture was being printed twice. I think it was because there was the command "endfig;" in my code

> \everyendmplib{endfig;}

and also at the end of TeXLabels.mp.

I just erased the last line of TeXLabels.mp and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you mention is in `\cyr` not being defined.

You should edit `TeXLabels.mp` to remove the initial part

```
verbatimtex
  \font\cyr=wncyr10
etex
```

and add a definition for `\cyr` in your TeX document. You also have a wrong declaration in `\everymplib`, that shouldn't include `beginfig(1);`, since the `beginfig` command is supplied in `TeXLabels.mp`. Similarly, you don't need `endfig;` in `\everyendmplib`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{OT2}{\rmdefault}{wncyr}
\providecommand{\cyr}{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont}

\everymplib{input mpcolornames;}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
  input TeXLabels.mp;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

[image]